# Observer and Observable got deprecated and the reason stated is: they convey something has changed but not state what has changed, this is false?

Tags: java, java-8, observer-pattern, java-9

[Check this by open jdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2eQh.png)

[deprecate Observer and Observable](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154801)

Observer and Observable Class:

Observable:-

```
class NewsAgency extends Observable {

String news;
public void setNews(String news) {
    this.news = news;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(news);
 }
}
```

Observers:-

```
public class IndiaNews implements Observer {
   @Override
   public void update(Observable o, Object news) {
   System.out.println("Indianews: " +news.toString());
 }
}

class AjjTak implements Observer {
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object news) {
    System.out.println("AjjTak: " +news.toString());
}
```

Main CLass:-

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewsAgency newsAgency = new NewsAgency();

    IndiaNews indiaNews = new IndiaNews();
    AjjTak ajjTak = new AjjTak();

    newsAgency.addObserver(indiaNews);
    newsAgency.addObserver(ajjTak);

    newsAgency.setNews("Yo");
}
```

}

**But I was able to tell the observer that news has changed**
*then How that above statement is true?*

Can anybody clear my thoughts?

**Thanks :)**

Comment: Don’t post screenshots of things you can cite as text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But I was able to tell the observer that news has changed then.  How that above statement is true?

The text from the [issue tracker link](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154801) says:

> *"For example, they support only the notion that something has changed, but they don't convey any information about what has changed."*

In your example, the `update` method call tells the observer that something has changed, but not what actually changed.  So, when you call `setNews("Yo")`, the `indiaNews` observer is told that `newsAgency` has changed.  But it is NOT told what the change was. The observer can use the `news` argument to see the *current* state of the `newsAgency`, but there is no way to see what the state was before the change, or indeed what it was *immediately* after the change<sup>1</sup>.

In many use cases for `Observer` / `Observable`, the application needs to know what actually changed to trigger the `update` call.

THAT is the deficiency that being highlighted, and it is *one* of the reasons for the deprecation.  The deprecation text in the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Observable.html) list others as well:

> *"This class and the `Observer` interface have been deprecated. The event model supported by `Observer` and `Observable` is quite limited, the order of notifications delivered by `Observable` is unspecified, and state changes are not in one-for-one correspondence with notifications. For a richer event model, consider using the `java.beans` package. For reliable and ordered messaging among threads, consider using one of the concurrent data structures in the `java.util.concurrent` package. For reactive streams style programming, see the `Flow` API."*

---

<sup>1 - Since the order of notification delivery is unspecified, the state of the observed object could have changed *again* by the time that the `update` call occurs.</sup>

Comment: If you can tweak my example then I'll appreciate you by my heart <3, although the clarification you provided has cleared my doubts about "what has changed was not conveyed" [CHANGE -> the difference of previous news and new news] much much thanks :)

Comment: I think, the text of the deprecation warning is misleading, as it focusses too much on details which could have been fixed or are even irrelevant, e.g. nothing in the documentation of `notifyObservers(Object)` says that the argument has to be the new value. It could be an object containing both values and even more meta information. And the “*the order of notifications*” isn’t a topic in the Java Beans event model either. That’s a red herring.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is too simple, as it features an object having exactly one property experiencing exactly one state change.

Things get far more complicated when an object has more than one property. But it’s also possible that a state change is not directly expressible as a simple property, like “user clicked on (x,y)”.

It’s not as if this API doesn’t allow to deliver the necessary information, as the source can deliver an arbitrary object which could be an event object containing all necessary information. But since this argument has type `Object` and Java 1.1 had no generics to declare specializations while staying binary compatible, such an object would be just a convention between the source and receiver. You would have to study the documentation to find out what you can expect.

These issues were addressed in Java 1.1 with the Java Beans event model. Information is conveyed through different mechanisms

- By type. We don’t need to iterate over registered `KeyListener`s when delivering a mouse event.
- By method. By invoking `mousePressed` instead of `mouseReleased`, the `MouseListener` knows implicitly what happened.
- By the typed event object. The `mousePressed` method receives a `MouseEvent` containing information about the button, the coordinates, but also whether, e.g. the shift key was pressed at the same time.

It was not possible to retrofit the `Observable`/`Observer` mechanism to the new design pattern, so it was just left alone, subject to sink into oblivion.

However, it was not marked deprecated for some reason.

The absence of such a marker or a redirection to the event mechanism/ Java Beans pattern led to people still trying to use it and stumble over deficiencies, wasting development time while the JDK developers actually considered the case closed:

Bug [JDK-4180466](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4180466), filed in 1998, reports missing serialization support. When a base class is not serializable, trying to add serialization support in a subclass would move the responsibility of storing and restoring the observers to the subclass, but there is no API to query the currently registered observers.

The response, back in 1999, was

> This class is no longer under active development. It is largely unused in
> the JDK, and has, for the most part, been superseded by the 1.1 Beans/AWT
> event model.

Note that bug [JDK-4212311](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4212311), filed two weeks later, states that the API documentation contradicts the actual behavior, `notifyObservers()` is supposed to call `clearChanged()` after notifying the observers, but calls `clearChanged()` *before* notifying the observers.

Nobody at Sun cared, as already stated, the API was practically abandoned and neither was the behavior fixed nor the documentation adapted to tell what the method actually does. Finally in 2016, in the process of deprecating `Observable`/`Observer`, it was closed as “won’t fix”.

But people kept wasting their time on this API, because its documentation didn’t tell them not to use it.

Like [JDK-4687908](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4687908) submitted in 2002 suggesting that `Observable` should be an interface. Which is right, but irrelevant because its successor does allow to define event source as interfaces.

Or [JDK-8025077](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8025077) submitted as late as 2013, worrying about the absence of documented thread safety policy in this abandoned API.

And these are the examples of people eventually submitting a bug report, we can only speculate how many people wasted efforts without submitting a report afterward.

---

In other words, the question shouldn’t be, why have `Observable`/`Observer` been deprecated, but rather, why did it take two decades from stopping maintenance for these classes to adding this information to the documentation.

---

The reason for the deprecation given in the documentation is, however, rather weird. The deprecated warning states “*the order of notifications delivered by `Observable` is unspecified, and state changes are not in one-for-one correspondence with notifications*”, but to stay at the mouse event notification example, the AWT components using a multi-caster do not guaranty a specific notification order either and listeners should not assume a particular order, in general. Further, movement events support coalescing, so we can’t assume a “one-for-one correspondence with notifications” and it’s not clear why this should be a goal, especially one so important that it justifies deprecation.

I think, the deprecation marker’s text should have been what has cited above:

> This class is no longer under active development. It is largely unused in the JDK, and has, for the most part, been superseded by the 1.1 Beans/AWT event model.

and perhaps

> This class has blatant bugs and design flaws which were not fixed for two decades now.

instead of reasoning about “notification order”, “one-for-one correspondence”, or whether it does “convey any information about what has changed”.